# Process for connecting to SignalR server

Tags: ios, swift, signalr

I am using the [AutosoftDMS/SignalR-Swift](https://github.com/AutosoftDMS/SignalR-Swift) client in order to connect my Swift/iOS app to a SignalR server.  My question is, what is the proper sequence to connect if the SignalR server supports different "rooms"?

Example #1:

```
let hubConnection = HubConnection(withUrl: <some SignalR server URL>)

let chatHub = hubConnection.createHubProxy(hubName: "RoomChatHub")

hubConnection.started = {      
    // the value 2 is some room identifier      
    self.chatHub.invoke(method: "RoomConnect", withArgs: [2])
}
```

The problem with this example is the **invoke** has no handler that would begin to receive messages from the SignalR server for room #2.

Example #2:

```
let hubConnection = HubConnection(withUrl: <some SignalR server URL>)

let chatHub = hubConnection.createHubProxy(hubName: "RoomChatHub")

chatHub.on(eventName: "RoomConnect") { (args) in
    if let message = args[0] as? String {
        print("Room Message: \(message)")
    }
}
```

The problem with this example is the **chatHub.on** method has no argument parameter that would allow me to specify that I want only messages for room #2.

How do you connect to a SignalR server in a way that I can say I want messages for some specific room?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use Groups. You would create a group for each room and connections to appropriate groups.

Comment: But that does not address the underlying issue.  I would have to pass the group name or some identifier and the way the client API is set up, I can pass that group name but there is no callback/handler to receive messages for that group.